# MySQL - выборка данных

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Есть база. В ней 2 таблицы.
Одна нам не понадобиться, а вторая имеет следующую структуру (все поля- INT-ы):

```
    uid     entry            turnout
     1    1299527463      1299537463
     1    1299547463      1299547463
     3    1299547567      1299547463
     1    1299578400      1299664800
```

Цель. 
Необходимо сформировать запрос, который покажет **ближайшее минимальное число** от числа **1299547900** из колонки **turnout**, которое будет относится к **uid 1**.

*Обращу Ваше внимание на то, что ни одна из колонок не уникальна.*

Comment: @Асисяськин Не забывайте принимать ответы (галочка), если они действительно отвечают на Ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT uid, turnout FROM table 
WHERE turnout > 1299547900 AND uid = 1 ORDER BY turnout LIMIT 1
```

Так?

Comment: Совершенно верно :))) .... Блин, я лошара :))) 
Я делал так: 

SELECT *
FROM timetable
WHERE entry <=1299664800
AND WHERE uid =3
ORDER BY entry DESC
LIMIT 1 

И зачем я второй раз WHERE писал ?:))) ... мда.. пора спать :) Спасибо, вопрос решен :)